# How to write unit test in symfony3

Tags: phpunit, symfony

I want to know how to write standard unit test code for the below controller. I believe PHPUNIT is installed by default in symfony3 but I'm not sure how to execute it as well. Can someone guide me how to write testcontroller and execution command for symfony3 as well.

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="user_registration")
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
     */
    public function userAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();

        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')  && $form->isValid()) {            
                $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                    ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
                $user->setPassword($password);

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                $this->get('app.mailer')->sendUserCredentials($user);

                $this->addFlash('notice', 'An account is created');
          }

        return $this->render('masteradmin/account/addUser.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route(
     *     "/user/edit/{id}",
     *      requirements={"id" = "\d+"},
     *      name="user_edit"
     * )
     */
    public function editUserAction(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $id = $request->attributes->get('id');

        if (!$user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneById($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('user details not found.');
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user)
                    ->remove('plainPassword');

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $data = $form->getData();

        if ($form->isValid()) {            
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('notice', 'Account information is updated');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_list');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'masteradmin/account/editUser.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]
        );
    }
```

Comment: Unit testing a controller is typically hard (and that appears to be the case here), and discouraged. You can write a functional test to make a request and investigate the response. Check the docs for examples: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#functional-tests

Comment: @Gerry. Thanks for your reply. I can look into functional testing. But I'm the situation like I should write unit test for the controller. Also I had already gone through the documentation link you provided. I feel it's not enough to get started. Is there any other good resource to start with.